# AdMob support in Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, admob, delphi-xe5

**Where can I find AdMob support for Android in Delphi XE5?**
I have tried to find it in all components but could not find anything. Should I make it myself using JNI, if so then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the steps in this post but i got an error 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'

http://www.dynadream.com/ddweb/index.php/Special_Blog?id=20

http://www.pclviewer.com/android/XE5.pdf

http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html

I do not Java, so if any one can proceed and tell us the problem.

Comment: your library is using a handler for asynchronous calls, and need to be run from a different Thread, not from the main thread. handling this in java code is much lighter and then it's easier to import in Delphi XE5...

Answer (score 1):

Importing an Android Class For Use in Delphi:
http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/108703

Answer (score 1):

Here is a AdMob component for xe5. I use this for Android:

http://www.flashavconverter.com/content/admob-android-delphi-component-11